# Select Data based on date from database

Tags: php, mysql

My below PHP is fetching the data from database for present data if exist in the the Sql table using the Time Zone Date and the id to select date for present date.

But;

I want it to select present week data in the sense if today is Sunday it should fetch the data from Monday to today if data exist in the table against that id

My database table is as follows

```
        Date                Id                Data to be fetched

2014-08-29 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-29 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-30 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-31 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-31 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-02 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-02 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-02 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-03 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-03 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-04 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
2014-08-04 00:00:00       12345                       ABC
```

PHP:code

```
<?php

  // This is used to select Time Zone
date_default_timezone_set("Indian/Chagos");
        $date= date("y-m-d 00:00:00");

        //Databse Connection
                $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','db');
    //Data From Ajax For Id to select data against that id

            $id= $_POST['storedValue'];
                //Sql Query
                                                                //Select data against date and PK Id
        $query ="SELECT * FROM master WHERE  StudentRegID='$id' And AttendanceDate='$date' ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
            //Echo result
      echo "{ y: ".$row[9]." ,label: '".$row[6]."'},";  
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

It is not working:

Can you identify where I am going wrong?

```
    $id= $_POST['storedValue'];
        $query ="SELECT * FROM master WHERE  StudentRegID='$id' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date) < 7 ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {



      echo "{ y: ".$row[9]." ,label: '".$row[6]."'},";




    }
```

Comment: @Strawberry Sry i dint get u

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF` between the column `Date` and your current date and retrieve only the lines where the difference is less than 7 like:

```
SELECT * [...]
WHERE  StudentRegID='$id' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), Date) < 7
-- if you want only the lines where something happened today :
AND DATE(AttendanceDate) = DATE('$date') 
;
```

Comment: It is not if you update the WHERE condition. I added a rule on the StudentRegId. That way, it will return the row that match one particular student id for the last 7 days.

Comment: Can u please Rehears My Question Iam not Getting if u Don't mind

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\working-DONOT-TOUCH\graph.php on line 14      It is showing the error as above

Comment: i have updated the Changed Code above it is not working Can u let me know where am i goin wrong

Comment: In the first answser, you use `master`, in the second `attendance_master`. Please correct indentation. You can also tests the query directly in SQL and see if returning results are okay.